# How to bring / design navigation drawer layout on top of MaterialCardView by clicking on ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-navigationview

I am trying to design the layout that drags navigation drawer layout from right to left by clicking on  ImageView which is menu icon.

Functionality is working without any issue. But, from UI perspective, navigation drawer layout is being visible below the MaterialCardView and wrapping content as the card size. How can i bring navigation drawer on top of card and full screen.

Below is my layout file:
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#1835d9"
        style="@style/CustomCardCorners"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="right"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items"/>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is my themes.xml:

```
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<style name="CustomCardCorners" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearance_custom_corners</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearance_custom_corners" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">40dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">40dp</item>
</style>
```

Below is my my_navigation_items.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:title="Test"/>
<item android:title="Second"/>
<item android:title="Third"/>

</menu>
```

Below is my MainActivity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

ImageView imageView;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
NavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//will hide the title
    this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    imageView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_icon);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    setUp();

}

private void setUp() {
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.navigation_icon:
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+ item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    return true;
}
}
```

[image: Below is the image with toast displaying the id of navigation item]

Comment: Try to play with elevation and transition-z

Comment: @Sekiro - I've tried your code. It is working as expected. but, action bar is also displaying along with it. 

Though I am hiding title and action bar programmatically, It is displaying. Is there any way to do it and make full screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chronology of the views is causing issues. As mentioned in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer), the correct chronology is

```
<DrawerLayout> 

<RootView> <!--root view of main content-->

<!--other child views-->

</RootView>

<NavigationView/> <!--view for navigation menu-->

</DrawerLayout>
```

so try the following layout instead

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="right">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                style="@style/CustomCardCorners"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#1835d9">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:onClick="onClick"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: @Eswar reordering the chronology as shown above solved your issue, working as expected on my device, Happy coding :)

Comment: I've tried your code. It is working as expected. but, action bar is also displaying along with it. Though I am hiding title and action bar programmatically, It is displaying. Is there any way to do it and make full screen?

Comment: just change your Apptheme to `NoActionBar` and remove `this.supportActionBar!!.hide()` from your activity

Comment: @Sekiro- Working fine now. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the drawer layout is under the `MaterialCardView` then this is for sure an "elevation" issue.

Based on Material.io [elevation docs](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html), the nav drawer layout has by default 16dp, whereas the `MaterialCardView` has from 1dp-8dp.

My guess is that you aren't using the Material's `DrawerLayout` component, or has they call it, `NavigationView`.

You can see how to implement it, in this [link](https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer/android#using-navigation-drawers)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, If i use elevation and set it to 16dp, upper part of MaterialCardView is invisible. As a result, ImageView is not displaying.

Comment: Also, I am sure that drawer layout is under the Card. As you can see my java file, I am using Toast to display the id of item in navigation layout and it is working as expected.

Comment: Is it possible for you to update your question with a screenshot?

Comment: I've edited a question and added image. Kindly have a look into it